# Integrating Leaflet map within a Grafana Panel?

Tags: leaflet, html

I am searching for hints on how to embed or implement a simple Leaflet map in a Grafana text panel (9.4.3 - html format), as there is no layer switch in Geomaps plug-in.
I have tried two things:

- I set disable_sanitize_html to true, called the map in an iframe
  inside a text box with html format. The panel only shows the html
  code.
- I copied the whole index.html including the script and leaflet
  sources into the content block expecting to get error messages which
  didn't happen. The panel just showed the code.

   Some googling led me to believe that it might be possible to import a leaflet map into a Grafana panel, but I could not find any tutorials or detailed explanations.

  Has anyone achieved this?

Comment: One possible solution would be to use Graphana AJAX panel plugin (https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/ryantxu-ajax-panel/, but Leaflet map would have to be hosted on some server.